# How to draw lines with dates on one axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph with dates on the x axis and a scalar on the y axis.

when I do this:

```
plt.plot_date([date_from, date_to], [0, 10000], fmt='-', color='r')
```

it works as expected (although I'm not sure what the fmt='-' part does and would be happy to learn about it)

but, having a lot of line segments, when I do this:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mpd
lines = [[(mpd.date2num(date_from), 0), (mpd.date2num(date_to), 10000)]]
c = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1)])
lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=2)
ax.add_collection(lc)
```

nothing is appearing; why is that?

Comment: Since you add a linecollection manually, you would also need to autoscale (e.g. `ax.autoscale()`) the axes. For the correct formatting of ticks, use `ax.xaxis_date()`. If this doesn't help, please provide complete runnable code (see [mcve]).

Comment: `...would be happy to learn...` - https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: ax.autoscale() did the trick. Thanks!